# PHP : Convert YYYY-MMM-DD to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: php, string, date, converters

I need to convert date string into number:

```
2012-Sep-01 to 2012-09-01
```

Any idea?
Regards,

Comment: What have you tried? I'm not a PHP person, but I'd look for date/time parsing and formatting libraries.

Comment: datetime.format()... but phpnet seams down....

Comment: we would love to help those people who help themselves ... you are supposed to do some searcher first than ask

Comment: @RegisteredUser, I've tried the research before and I knew that the date() format and strtotime() works fine this way but the problem is the dynamic value is not passed so I can't get the expected date. Sometimes some problem is not because I don't do the research but for some over-programmed makes me confused. So If you don't want to answer just be quiet. And thanks for those who make my simple question clear. And I'm really sure that those useful answer here will be values for someone else than yours.

Answer (score 6):

This might work for you:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($yourCurrentDateVat))'
```

PHP website is down at the moment, but [here is some extra info](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp) on the date function.

Comment: Yes, I did, Good Mihai popped in with the freaky-fast edit of the format :)

Answer (score 6):

Try to use DateTime PHP class:

```
$date = "2012-Sep-01";
$result = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-M-d", $date)->format("Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `strtotime()`:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2012-Sep-01'));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-M-j', '2012-Sep-01');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Actually stolen from the manual: http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 1):

You should use `strtotime()`. More info on [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). And then `date()` to create a new string. More info on that [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
$date = '2012-Sep-01'; //Sets your date string
$time_epoch = strtotime($date); //Converts the string into an epoch time
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', $time_epoch); //Creates a new string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$timestamp = strtotime('22-09-2008');
$new_date = date("y-m-d", $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi, try using this in PHP and you will surely get what you want, I was searching for the same but didn't found but later discovered I had the date-time formula used somewhere and modified it to get this.

`$getdatetime=date_create('2020-May-21');
$dateconverted=date_format($getdatetime,'Y-m-d'); 
echo $dateconverted;`